# Merging remote Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

I have started a new project on Google code, and I chose Mercurial as VCS. I forced a push over the remote repository, since it created two heads, problem is: now I don't know how to merge this two heads on the remote repository!

Please help, it's my first time with Mercurial, and I want it to be as painless as possible ;)
Oh, and forgive the succynthness of my question. If extra information is needed, tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem.  Just clone that repo to a new clone locally (now you'll have two heads), do a `hg merge` locally followed by a `hg commit` locally (now you'll have one head locally) and then `hg push` to remote (now you'll have one head remotely).

That merge changeset you're creating when you merge has two parents, so it removes a head for whomever has it.